# Importing JAVE in Blue J

Tags: java, import, lib, jave

Whenever I try and import a lib into blue j, in this case JAVE in order to convert WAV files into MP3, the library never seems to import properly, and I get error messages such as "package it.sauronsoftware does not exist" and "cannot find class". I have tried using the blue J add libraries tool in preferences as well as putting the jar file in the lib folder and putting the jar file in the class path. I do not seem to be able to get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you use a normal IDE Eclipse, idea, or even netbeans.

Comment: I will try that straight way, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your bluej software and install the latest